# ¿Como puedo consultar varios elementos de una base de datos con un mismo identificador? -SQLite-Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Quiero consultar en Android Studio una base de datos de SQLite. Teniendo una base de datos de personas , la cual tiene los campos edad y nombre. Lo que quiero es extraer de la base de datos todas las personas que tengan 19 años.

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = OpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String buscar[] ={"19"};
    String campos[] = {Utilidad.CAMPO_NOMBRE};
    Cursor cursor = db.query("personas",campos,Utilidad.CAMPO_EDAD+"=?",buscar,null,null,null);
```

En el codigo anterior se ve lo que programe yo en un principio, pero tengo entendido que en el cursor queda almacenada la primera persona que encuentro con 19 años , ¿Pero si quisiera almacenar todas las personas que pueden aparecer con 19 años que debería hacer?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Todas las personas que tengan 19 años o no importando su edad ?

Comment: Todas las personas que tengan 19 quiero recuperar.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Pues aparentemente tu código esta perfecto, suponiendo que efectivamente en tu tabla tienes almacenados muchos registros de personas que cumplan con esa condición, ¿estas seguro que en el cursor únicamente tienes como resultado un solo registro?

Comment: En realidad como esta  definido tu query estas realizando lo que deseas, agrego una explicación @JoaquinMiranda . No olvides realizar el [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el método [query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[]
>   selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String
>   limit)

Donde:

> **selection** : String: un filtro que declara las filas a devolver,
>   formateadas como una cláusula `WHERE` de SQL (excluyendo `WHERE`). Pasar
>   nulo devolverá todas las filas para la tabla dada.

y

> **selectionArgs**: String: Puede incluir ?'s en la selección, que será reemplazada por los valores de selectionArgs, para que aparezcan en la
>   selección. Los valores estarán `ligados` como cadenas.

**En realidad lo que requieres se realizaría con el query que muestras en tu pregunta**, en este caso estas buscando todos los registros donde el campo edad tenga un valor "19", todos los valores se almacenarían en el cursor.

---

Si deseas obtener en el cursor únicamente el primer elemento usa el parametro:

> **limit** : String: limita el número de filas devueltas por la consulta, formateada como cláusula LIMIT. Pasar nulo no indica ninguna
>   cláusula LIMIT.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("personas",campos,Utilidad.CAMPO_EDAD+"=?",buscar,null,null, "1" /* este es el parametro limit! */);
```

Comment: Claramente el código estaba bien, estaba utilizando mal el cursor para acceder a los datos.

Comment: @JoaquinMiranda exactamente, en realidad si obtenías todas las personas con 19 años.